# over a Field extension

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, field-theory, extension-field, ring-isomorphism

> Let $f(x) = ax^2+bx+c \in \Bbb{R}[x]$ be an irreducible polynomial. Prove that the field $\Bbb{R}[x] \mathbin{/} \langle f(x) \rangle$ is isomorphic to the field of complex numbers.

Knowing that
$$
\Bbb{R}[x] \mathbin{/} \langle f(x) \rangle = \{h + gv \mid h, g \in \Bbb{R};\, av^2+bv+c = 0 \},
$$
how can I detect an element $\alpha \in\Bbb{R}[x] \mathbin{/} \langle f(x) \rangle$ such that $\alpha^2 = -1$?

Comment: To solve the cited problem you don't need to do this, but if you're intent on finding such an $\alpha$, use the $abc$-formula.

Comment: Map $v$ to $i.$

Comment: You need to fix your title as it is not at all useful.

Comment: I'm agree with you .Do you have some advice?

Comment: @BenSteffan.How would you approach its resolution ?